# changing default breakpoints in material ui is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the default breakpoints in material ui from

```
\node_modules\@material-ui\system\breakpoints.js
```

and for example I change the value of sm from 600px to 426px

```
var values = {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 426,
  md: 960,
  lg: 1280,
  xl: 1920
};
```

and my components are rendered like so :

```
<Box display={{ xs: 'none',sm:"block"}}>
  <Row direction={"row-reverse"} divider={true} />
</Box>
```

I want the Box component to be hidden when screen width is smaller than 426px with the code I said it works but it hides the component when the width is smaller than 600px which is the default value of sm breakpoint so the value I entered is ignored by the theme provider

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass the breakpoint values to the theme option like this as stated in [Material-UI docs](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#responsive)

```
const values = {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 426,
  md: 960,
  lg: 1280,
  xl: 1920
};

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    keys: ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
    up: (key) => `@media (min-width:${values[key]}px)`
  }
});
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit Material-UI Breakpoints]

Comment: yes as I said I am editing the material ui default files and it should change the default theme and the material ui itself is handling this part of code that you wrote and thats working but not with the values I changed in the material ui but with the default values

Comment: why do you want to change the library code directly instead of overriding it using material-ui API?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3b5302bf434d757b7a2b1997974dd4f8b12c2fc7/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createBreakpoints.js#L10-L16) @mohammadtz55